# Python [child] process sending message to Node [parent] process

Tags: python, node.js, ipc, child-process

[Python process forked by NodeJS - Alternative to process.send() for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804434/python-process-forked-by-nodejs-alternative-to-process-send-for-python)

I followed the solution above but doesnt seem to work (no messages are being send by the child python code. Here is my code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('python3', ['child.py'], {
    stdio:[null, null, null, 'pipe']
});

child.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Received message...');
    console.log(message);
});
```

and

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
import os

os.write(3, str.encode("HELLO"))
```

I can see what could go wrong. Please help.

Comment: `'python3', ['child.py']` where is `python3` ? in your friend computer ? `what is differences on default and declaration ?`

Answer (score 1):

I think the fourth parameter needs to be 'ipc' not 'pipe' to enable this style of message passing.

> 'ipc' - Create an IPC channel for passing messages/file descriptors
>   between parent and child. A ChildProcess may have at most one IPC
>   stdio file descriptor. Setting this option enables the
>   subprocess.send() method. If the child writes JSON messages to this
>   file descriptor, the subprocess.on('message') event handler will be
>   triggered in the parent. If the child is a Node.js process, the
>   presence of an IPC channel will enable process.send(),
>   process.disconnect(), process.on('disconnect'), and
>   process.on('message') within the child.
>
> https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

From the description of the fork which sets this up by default (unlike spawn for other languages):

> stdio  |  See child_process.spawn()'s stdio. When this
>   option is provided, it overrides silent. If the array variant is used,
>   it must contain exactly one item with value 'ipc' or an error will be
>   thrown. For instance [0, 1, 2, 'ipc'].
>
> https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options