# Node.js IPC between a Python parent and a Node.js child

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, ipc

Node.js has [integrated JSON-based IPC](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesssendmessage-sendhandle-options-callback):

```js
// main.js

const cp = require('node:child_process');
const n = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/sub.js`);

n.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
});

// Causes the child to print: CHILD got message: { hello: 'world' }
n.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

```js
// sub.js

process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});

// Causes the parent to print: PARENT got message: { foo: 'bar', baz: null }
process.send({ foo: 'bar', baz: NaN });
```

How can I write `main.js` in Python? I understand that this [isn't supported](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio):

> ... using the IPC channel with a child process that is not a Node.js instance is not supported

But can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The IPC channel in Node.js is just a simple bidirectional pipe. Channel's initialization starts [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ef33e93101c620876ad9d1195b0f79dfe90a4254/lib/internal/process/pre_execution.js#L449-L466). The serialization happens [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ef33e93101c620876ad9d1195b0f79dfe90a4254/lib/internal/child_process/serialization.js#L131-L162), each message is just a newline-trailing string of JSON.

`main.js` can be rewritten as follows:

```py
# main.py

import json
import multiprocessing
import os
import subprocess

parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
env = os.environ.copy()
env['NODE_CHANNEL_FD'] = str(child_conn.fileno())

subprocess.Popen(
    ['node', 'sub.js'],
    pass_fds=(child_conn.fileno(),),
    env=env,
)

parent_conn._write(parent_conn.fileno(), json.dumps({ 'hello': 'world' }).encode("ascii") + b'\n')
print('PARENT got message: ' + str(json.loads(parent_conn._read(parent_conn.fileno(), 1000))))
```

This will work with `sub.js` as-is! Using `multiprocessing.Pipe` because it's a duplex and multi-platform. `parent_conn._read` and `parent_conn._write` because they use [custom code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/330f1d58282517bdf1f19577ab9317fa9810bf95/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L358-L367) on Windows.

This is of course just a proof of concept, more code is needed to match Node.js' IPC ergonomics, but it works!

[This will likely be used in the LSP plugin for Sublime Text.](https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP/issues/1612#issuecomment-1207512726)